# Using std:: string in hdf5 creates unreadable output

Tags: c++, utf-8, character-encoding, hdf5, hdf

I'm currently using hdf5 1.8.15 on Windows 7 64bit.
The sourcecode of my software is saved in files using utf8 encoding.

As soon as I call any hdf5 function supporting std:: string, the ouput gets cryptic

[image]

But if I use `const char*` instead of `std::string`, everything works fine. This applies also to the filename.

Here is a short sample:

```
std::string filename_ = "test.h5";    
H5::H5File file( filename_.c_str(), H5F_ACC_TRUNC); // works

H5::H5File file( filename_, H5F_ACC_TRUNC); // filename is not readable or
                                            // hdf5 throws an exception
```

I guess that this problem is caused by different encodings used in my source files and hdf5. But I'm not sure about this and found no solution allowing the use of `std::string`s. I would appreciate any idea which helps me with this issue.

Comment: Sounds more like conflicting implementations of the standard library, or some other conflict. The encoding in your source file is 100% irrelevant.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. Instead of using the provided precompiled binaries I compiled hdf5 by myself and the error is gone.

Comment: @user2445483 Could you maybe describe in more detail what you did? Because I have the same issue, however, it is not gone after I compiled the hdf5 files by myself.

Comment: Ok, i found the issue (see below).

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem, and fixed it by changing all my std::string or h5std_string to literally:

```
5File file("myFile.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
```

Or use `string.c_str()` to change the string to `const char`.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. The solution was, that I was in Debug-Mode in Visual Studio, whereas the libraries I linked against were build in Release-Mode. When I switched in Visual Studio to Release-Mode, the above error disappeared.