# Problems with stdstring and hdf5

Tags: c++, visual-c++, hdf5, stdstring

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (HDF5 v1.8.12) and I have problems with each function a H5std_string as argument.

---

This is even the case when I run the example file "create.cpp"
https://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/c++/examples/create.cpp

This gives me the error:
....\H5F.c line 1466 in H5Fcreate(): invalid file name
The error is fixed when I replace `FILE_NAME` with `FILE_NAME.c_str()`
and  `DATASET_NAME` with  `DATASET_NAME.c_str()`

---

Similarily I get an error when running:

```
H5::Attribute attr = group.openAttribute("type");
H5std_string attr_content;
attr.read(attr.getStrType(), attr_content);
```

however following code works

```
char buf[1024];
H5::Attribute attr = group.openAttribute("type");
attr.read(attr_date.getStrType(), buf);
```

Comment: I think you should call `getDataType()` instead of `getStrType()`

Comment: using getDataType() does not help. The problem is purely related to using a stdstring. Functions using `char*` work fine, however I get an error whenever I use the corresponding function taking `H5std_string` as  argument.

Comment: Looks similar to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072272/using-stdstring-in-hdf5-creates-unreadable-output

Answer (score 0):

The below shown error disappeared when switching in Visual Studio to Release-Mode.

[Using std:: string in hdf5 creates unreadable output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072272/using-stdstring-in-hdf5-creates-unreadable-output)